# Set path of views and controller for my PLUGIN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How i change the path of views folder to myplugin folder when i make new plugin.

Every time i call an action whose controller is in myplugin's folder.
Please help me each time it call the view of my app and not vendor/plugin/myplugin/views folder

Please help me
Thanks  in Advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not dry, but  for each action controller, you can call an explicit *render* pointing to a custom path.

UPDATE an year later, a better solution:

```
prepend_view_path "#{Rails.root}/vendor/plugins/yourplugin/path_to_views/"
```

more info here:
http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/ViewPaths/prepend_view_path